# Changing position from relative to fixed using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fixed

I want the following object to have position fixed, but it has to be  located 800 px aprox from top margin below the slideshow, this means outside my screen size.I was told it can be made with jquery- toogle class but can t manage to do it myself - Thanks so much for your help!

http://vtwg.eu/ZMT/untitled3.html   (website where element is not showing up)

Victoria

```
<div id="book-now">
<a href="mailto:musictours@zzkrecords.com?subject=Music_Tours"><img 
src="book_now.png" alt="" width="90"></img></a>
</div> 


#book-now{
position: fixed;
top: 800px;
right: 100px;
width: 160px;
height: 120px;
text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: what does jquery have to do with this? It's probably off screen because your `top` value is `800px`. Where do you want it to appear? What exactly is the problem with the thing as it is?

Comment: the div already has a fixed position ?? what do you want exactly ?

Comment: Hi! The problem is I need the object to appear somewhere 800px from top margin, a bit below the slideshow and then stay that you can see it when you scroll down. Am i being more clear? Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: @MichaelCoker Hi! The problem is I need the object to appear somewhere 800px from top margin, a bit below the slideshow not on top of it  just next to the zizek tours title...and then stay that you keep  seeing it  it when you scroll down. Am i being more clear? Thanks for your answers :) –

Comment: @VictoriaG. it's there 800px from the top of the screen but it probably isn't working like you want since not everyone has an 800px tall screen and your slider resizes with the viewport, meaning the link is visible for narrow/tall screens, not visible for wide/short screens. this likely has nothing to do with jquery. You just need to come up with what you want to do with the icon exactly and use CSS. http://i.imgur.com/gFsRAmZ.png

Comment: @MichaelCoker thanks for your answer, its clear now how it works. I would like the icon  to show up just exactly where you are seeing it but in wide short screens too... what would your sugggstion for the css then be?

Comment: It sounds like this https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/ according to the title.

Comment: @VictoriaG. I would remove `top: 800px`, add `bottom: 50px` and change `right: 100px` to `right: 50px`, then add `z-index: 9999` so it appears on top of everything else.

Comment: @MichaelCoker thanks! But with those properties the image shows up on top of the slideshow on the wide short screens and I need it to be next to the zizek title :/

Comment: @VictoriaG. you want it to always be next to the "zizek" title? Or you want it to be there when the page loads, and then when you scroll you want it to stay at the bottom/right of the screen?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes, like you are saying -   there when the page loads, and then when you scroll you want it to stay at the bottom/right of the screen or aprox. thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to measure `scrollTop();` and if it goes beyond a certain value (in your case, 800px, in this example - 300px) then give it a fixed position in your id of `#book-now`

Check it out below:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll >= 300) {
    $(".fixed-header").addClass("fixedPos");
}
else{

    $(".fixed-header").removeClass("fixedPos");
}
 });
```

```css
.fixed-header {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 0;
}

/*the fixed snippet, triggered by js*/
.fixedPos{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
}

.fixed-header__nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="fixed-header">
  <ul class="fixed-header__nav">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li> Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you use a normal desktop screen, then its behind your big picture :)
If you add a z-index: 1; it will be above it. Do you realy want it to be always on 800px? On Small devices it never will be within the viewable area.

Comment: Yes you are right and to work it with all device she needs jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you are unfamiliar with JQuery. Try these changes in css;

```
#header1 {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100000;
}


.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 2000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    z-index: 100000;
}  
#book-now{
    position: fixed;
    top: 550px;
    right: 100px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: right;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```